# How to install Bluedroid in a Linux environment?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I am using 64bit Ubuntu 16.03; This is my first time working in a Linux environment; I am working on BLE and now has to implement my code in a Linux environment, and is required to work with Bluedroid. For my dev purposes in BLE which version of Bluedroid should I install and how will I go about doing it ?

Comment: Why do you believe that the Android Bluetooth stack will work under non-Android Linux?

Comment: An impossible requirement is impossible, regardless of how required it is.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it can be used but not easily...

You have to have little expertise in C Programming .

Check ESP32 , they are using Bluedroid in FReeRTOS.

You have to go in similar way .. so basically You have to write your own application layer routines to drive the API of Bluedroid.

ESP32 people have used snipped version of bluedroid .i.e. All the Java Codes has been dropped from bluedroid .. and they have written simple basic application which talks to the top layer of Bluedroid C Files.

Short Answer to your question is: Yes it is achievable and if you follow the ESP32 way , You can have bluedroid running all in User Space.